# SQL: Divide the sum of values in one table with the count of rows in another

Tags: sql

Is it possible to, in a single query, sum a bunch of values in one table, and divide it by the count of rows in another? There is a common ID/key in both tables...

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What do the tables look like?

Answer (score 3):

FYI, you win points for the least info provided in a question.  The answer is it's possible...here is psuedo code since I'm guessing at your tables and columns

```
select summing / counting as whynot
from
(select id, sum(whatever) as summing from where_ever ) a
inner join
(select id, count(1) as counting from what_ever)b
on a.id = b.id
where question = 'vague'
group by a.id
```

Comment: Please don't use single quotes for the names of columns.  Although permitted in some databases, it leads to confusion and problems.  Use double quotes if you must.  It is better to choose names that are not reserved words so quoting is not necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff old habits die hard.  Corrected

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select sum(x) from table1 where ...) / (select count(*) from table2 where ...)
```

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing more about your specific situation, you could do something like this if your row count in another was constant (10):

```
SELECT SUM(columnName)/10 FROM tableName
```